# How to build a IMS open source corpus workbench and NLTK readable corpus?

Tags: python, nltk, corpus

Currently i've a bunch of .txtfiles. within each .txt files, each sentence is separated by newline. how do i change it to the IMS CWB format so that it's readable by CWB? and also to nltk format.

Can someone lead me to a howto page to do that? or is there a guide page to do that, i've tried reading through the manual but i dont really know. www.cwb.sourceforge.net/files/CWB_Encoding_Tutorial.pdf

Does it mean i create a data and registry directory and then i run the cwb-encode command and it will be all converted to vrt file? does it convert one file at a time? how do i script it to run through multiple file in a directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to produce cwb's "verticalized" format from an NLTK-readable corpus:

```
from nltk.corpus import brown

out = open('corpus.vrt','w')
for sentence in nltk.brown.sents():
     print >>out,'<s>'
     for word in sentence:
          print >>out,word
     print >>out,'</s>'
out.close()
```

From there, you can follow the [instructions on the CWB website](http://cogsci.uni-osnabrueck.de/~korpora/ws/CWBdoc/CWB_Encoding_Tutorial/node3.html).

Comment: Thanks malouf. i've vrt-lized them. i am using the cQP web to host the GUI to the corpus, how to i create the meta-data file for the corpus? do i create one meta-data for each file, or one meta-data file for the whole corupus?

Comment: For your information the link is no longer available.